# Solr query field Mandatory for query search

Tags: php, solr, lucene

I am using Bitnami Apache Solr 7.4.0(Latest)

I indexd documents

Now in admin Panel for query search i need to write **field:value** format

But I just want to search with only **value**

Example:

> q=field:value  (It works)
>
> q=value (It give 0 result)

So what should i configure in schema.xml file that i can search through only by Value of the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solr Admin --> Query page, you can add the field name to **df** to which you want to route your queries. df means **default search field**.In order to use you dont need to use dismax or edismax parsers. df will work with Standard Query parser itself. So, I hope this is what you are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the schema. You can create your own request handler which can perform query operations based on your requirements by creating a new `requestHandler` in the `solrconfig.xml` file. For more details on how to do this see [here](http://%20https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html).

That being said, I would suggest you first go through the basics of querying in solr and understand how the different parameters like `q`, `qf`, `defType` etc. work and what different query parsers (standard, dismax etc.) are available for use. See [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to configure, but you have to use the edismax or dismax query parsers. These query parses are made to support free form user input, and you can use it with just `q=value`. You tell Solr to use the edismax query parser by providing `defType=edismax` in the query URL.

Since the field to search no longer is part of the actual query, you tell the edismax handler which field to search by giving the `qf` parameter. You can give multiple fields in `qf`, and you can give each field different weights by using the syntax `field^<weight>`.

So to get the same result as in your first example:

```
?q=value&defType=edismax&qf=field
```